# Can we apply $\dfrac{ \sin ( u ) }{ u } = 1$ when ${ u }$ approaches $0$ even when there are other variables in the sin function?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, trigonometry

I have an equation:

$$
  \displaystyle\lim_{ δx   \rightarrow  0  }   \dfrac{  \sin \left(\left(  x+ \dfrac{ δx  }{ 2  } \right)      δx \right) }{  \left( x+ \dfrac{ δx  }{ 2  }    \right)  δx  }      
$$

The solution says that it is equal to $1$ because of the $ \dfrac{  \sin (  u   )    }{ u  }   =  1 $ when ${ u }$ approaches $0$ limit theorem.

But I don't understand how that can be applied here, since the equation has both $δx$ and $x$, so how can the theorem still be applicable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t = \left( x+ \dfrac{ \delta x  }{ 2  }    \right)  \delta x .$

Notice that:

$$\lim_{\delta x \to 0} t = 0.$$

Then:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{ \delta x   \rightarrow  0  }   \dfrac{  \sin \left(\left(  x+ \dfrac{ \delta x  }{ 2  } \right)      \delta x \right) }{  \left( x+ \dfrac{ \delta x  }{ 2  }    \right)  \delta x  } = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} = 1.$$

Comment: Without putting some emphasis on the requirements on the function $t = t(x,\delta x)$ in order to use this type of substitution, I'm not convinced this answer adds any clarity to the solution OP already has.

Comment: On the other hand, this is simply not true. Let $\delta_n = n^{-5/2}$, $x_n = n^{3/2}$. Then $\delta_n x_n\to 0$, but $t_n\to \infty$ when $n\to \infty$.

Comment: @Ennar I think in the question $\delta x$ is an "infinitesimal" and does not mean $\delta \cdot x$.

Comment: @Gary, you are probably right, that does make sense. Still, I don't approve of that notation without any context.

Comment: @Ennar I wouldn't be terribly surprised if the original source used $\Delta x$ instead (which is a bit more standard) and OP just used the lower-case without recognizing the difference.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, yes, $\Delta x$ is standard enough that nobody thinks of $\Delta$ as a variable, but $\delta$ is, unfortunately, very standard variable in analysis. There are instances where I saw $\delta$ used as an operator of some kind, but I think something like that should be explicitly mentioned.

Comment: I don't understand how the original limit $limδx→0$ turned into $limt→0$

Comment: @kronaemmanuel You are a new user here, so I think we should cut you some slack. Clicking the green check mark means you fully or at least mostly accept the answer to a question. Please only do this if you actually do understand and accept the answer. You can also *uncheck the green check mark now* if you want to (i.e. if you don't feel satisfied with this answer.)

Comment: What Adam said was what I mean to say. Thank you @AdamRubinson.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about the general limit

$$ \lim_{y\to L} \frac{\sin(u(y))}{u(y)} $$

where $u(y)\to 0$ as $y\to L\in\mathbb{R}$.

Well, so long as there does not exist a sequence $y_n$ in the domain of $u(y)$ such that $y_n \overset{n\to\infty}{\to} L$ and $u(y_n) = 0 $ for each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ then this is equivalent to there existing a neighbourhood around $L$ such that $u(y) \neq 0$ for all $y$ in this neighbourhood. Then in this case, I do not see why we would not have:

$$ \lim_{y\to L} \frac{\sin(u(y))}{u(y)} = 1. $$

I believe you could also replace $L$ with $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ from the start, and the above reasoning would also hold.